# sharepoint 2010 document library event receivers item added event when uploading a file

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2010 in document library using event receivers when uploading a file using `itemadded` event. In the event get the properties of the file it will changed because the file contains same properties in the custom tab of properties of the file. so the `SPListItem` properties will not come, so how to clear the file custom properties when uploading a file in sharepoint please help me.

I am set to `ItemAddedCol` is default value is set to `false`, but i will shown in true. Problem is I am uploading a file that extension is *.ppt*. The file properties and go to custom tab set add some fileds like `ItemAddedCol`, `File Size`. So these values are taking how to clear these custom fields in item added event.

```
string size = Convert.ToInt32(listitem["File Size"]);
statusupdate = Convert.ToString(listitem["ItemAddedCol"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but when you upload file into document library, setting custom properties invokes ***item updating*** events. You should be able to write your event receiver for `ItemUpdated` (or `ItemUpdating`) event and clear properties you want here.

So the code can look something like this:

```
public virtual void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties, bool isCheckIn)
{
    try
    {
        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;

        //clear value in your custom column
        listItem["myCustomColumnName"] = null;

        listItem.Update(); //or listItem.SystemUpdate()
    }
    finally
    {
        this,EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, so let me know if you have any issues when running it.